# Chrome for window devtools freezes

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm using chrome on Windows 7 and after updating from 48 to 49, the devtools get frozen when I'm trying to navigate some of the tabs (sources, resources, etc.)

I re-installed several times, and restored devtools options to default, but none of the attempts worked for me.

I downgraded to 43 and works fine.
Anyone knows the reason or experiencing same problem?

Comment: Norton antivirus just told me 2 minutes ago that chrome.exe was  downloaded. I now have Version 49.0.2623.87 m (64-bit)

Comment: This bug seems somewhat similar https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=593679&q=component%3APlatform%3EDevTools&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified